# Multiple domains with wrong SSL certificate on the load balancer

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

Let me preface that I am not a load balancer expert, but I know that if you offload an SSL certificate on the load balancer you have multiple advantages.

One of our clients wants to cache many websites through a CDN using SSL. For the sake of argument, let's pretend the sites are https://siteone.com and https://sitetwo.com

They want to install on the load balancer a "wrong certificate" (for example a certificate with CN: origin.oursites.com) so that they don't have to continue to update the certificate every time that a new site is added to the CDN caching. They say that this can be done because the CDN allows for a mismatch of certificate.

My question, and it might be a stupid one, is the following: if the certificate don't match, how can the load balance decrypt each package and find out the exact URL that is being requested and figure out which servers should the package being sent to? What am I missing?

Can you please help me understand if this is really feasible and, if so, why does it work, please?

Thanks in advance,
// Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regarding "if the certificate don't match, how can the load balance decrypt each package", it's rather the case that the validation of the certificate is a precondition to exchanging the (symmetric) encryption keys. If you remove the validation step (or parts of it) it makes it more likely that you succeed in establishing the encrypted connection, not the other way around.
The problem is that now you have a working encrypted connection, but you don't actually know who the other party is; it could be the party you tried to connect to but it could also be anyone else who was able to intercept your connection.

If the CDN allows a mismatched certificate at the origin, without any further qualifications, then that's horrible security practice.
This would allow for trivial man-in-the-middle attacks (as per above) as absolutely anyone can present a signed but mismatched certificate and be accepted as the origin.

If, however, the CDN has some other means of validating the origin certificate, such as pinning (recognizing the certificate itself rather than relying on the chain of trust + matching subject name) this one valid certificate used for these origins, and with that in place then ignoring the subject name, that would be fine as it wouldn't allow for anyone else's mismatched certificates to be accepted. It actually changes the validation to an overall much more strict model.

Comment: Yes it seems it would use pinning - so the load balancer would then be able to decrypt the packages and understand their content (e.g. Domain, URL, etc)?

Comment: @FrancescoGallarotti If the CDN accepts the certificate, then yes, it would work. Just make absolutely sure that there really is some other security measure in place (eg pinning).

Answer (score 1):

Not stupid at all. To answer your question, a certificate mismatch, meaning the name on the certificate doesn't match the requested URL, will not affect the actual encryption. If the warning about the mismatched name can be ignored, the data will still be sent / received encrypted just as if it was a valid match.

It is however, not good practice. The current security landscape means that SSL checks and certificate validation will become tighter, so the CDN accepting a mismatch is not something you can be sure will stay that way.

An option for your customer would be to use a [wildcard certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate), i.e. for mysites.com that would work with site1.mysites.com, site2.mysites.com, site*n*.mysites.com

Comment: Wildcard certificates cannot be used since these domains are all over the place, with hundreds of different names and sub domains.